# how to customize notification panel

Tags: android

I am pretty new to android. I am trying create an app that customizes the expanded view of the notification panel . For start , I would like to add one button at the top of the notifications panel that will delete the message.I have checked the reference from http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html , however , this is not helping much as it is the view of the each notification . That is not what I want , I want to add the button at the top of the panel for any notification. Could you please direct me what should or how should I go about doing that. Any idea , reference would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying create an app that customizes the expanded view of the notification panel...I want to add the button at the top of the panel for any notification.

You are welcome to create your own custom firmware for this. It is not possible via an Android SDK application.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. No wonder , I was not going any where with the sdk